# What's in-memory persistence in Java

Tags: java, oop, servlets, persistence

I am working on a simple java project and I read from the project specification which says "must provide some forms of in-memory persistence of created object". How to understand in-memory persistence? Should I serialize my object and store it in MySQL?

Comment: No. An array or a map or a list would suffice. As long as it's in memory. Alternatively, something like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) is also "in-memory".

Comment: This term is a bit confusing if not an oxymoron: in-memory is not considered persistent (a restart of the machine will cause data loss)... I guess that this is one of the cases where the context has all the meaning...

Answer (score 2):

## Oxymoron

*In-memory persistence* is a contradiction in terms.

[Persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)) is “state that outlives the process that created it” according to Wikipedia. Means that your important data should survive the exit of your app and the shutdown of the computer. Everything in memory disappears at that time. So persistence requires storage on a non-[volatile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_memory) medium.

For Java, that might take various routes:

- [Serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)
- [Exporting data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Import_and_export_of_data) to a file
- Writing data to a [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database), usually via [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity).

Some database can live in memory rather than written to storage, but that means all data is lost when the database engine stops. Good for some tasks such as testing but cannot save your data long-term.

You must consult the author of those requirements to clarify their intentions.